# Merge ableton and ableton-live?

Tags: discussion, tags

They appear to be the same thing. If there is a difference, it is unlikely that new users would know. I propose the we merge, or make them synonyms

Answer (score 1):

Ableton make various products, one of which is Ableton Live. Another is Ableton Push

It may be worthwhile removing the Ableton tag, but not merging it with Ableton Live.